# SQL Server Update query taking too long

Tags: python, sql, sql-server

I am fetching data from a column, sorting it and updating another column in the same table with the sorted result corresponding to each record. The sorting takes 12 minutes for 170,000 records but the updation is taking 5 hours. Is there a way to fasten the updation? Below is my code:

```
connection = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL 
Server};SERVER=server_name;DATABASE=db_name)
cursor = connection.cursor()
query = """update tbl set sorted_data= (?) where Id= (?)"""
for row1 in rows1:  
     srow1 = re.split(';|,|\s', row1[0])
     sortrow1 = ';'.join(sorted(srow1, key=str.lower))
     values.append((sortrow1,row1[1]))
     count=count+1
cursor.executemany(query,values)
connection.commit()
connection.close()
```

Comment: With this code, you are performing 170,000 individual UPDATE statements. When you start, the first thing the SQL Server does is compile that entire batch of UPDATE statements. And UPDATEMany IS VERY SLOW!

Comment: See this discussion for more details: https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/120

Comment: I see 'turbodbc' mentioned in the discussion that does batch updates. I'll test using that. Thank you! @Laughing Vergil